# Cannot up the basic sever written with hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Today, I decided to play with one of node.js frameworks, hapi.js. I followed their [getting started](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/?lang=en_US) guide, installed `hapi` and put code that is required to spin up a basic server, inside `index.js` and set `npm start` to `node index.js`. After doing all these, when I tried running the server with `npm start`, I was greeted with the following error..:-(. Any help to overcome this is highly appreciated.

```js
F:\app-Backend\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\core.js:51
   actives = new WeakMap();                                                   // Active requests being processed
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-backend@1.0.0 start: `node ./index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app-backend@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pavindu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-13T08_45_49_367Z-debug.log
```

**index.js**

```js
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');

const init = async () => {

    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 8080,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works for me.

Have you remembered to `npm install @hapi/hapi --save`?

So this is because the latest version of hapi will only work on node 12+

Comment: Yes, I have, but still I can't get it to work..:- (. What I can't understand is why hapi gives this error. I can run express.js apps on my computer without any problem..

Comment: I can confirm: code works for me too (`node -v v13.2.0`, `npm -v 6.14.4`, `@hapi/hapi: ^19.1.1)`.

Comment: `the latest version of hapi will only work on node 12+` < -- this should be the reason that it's not working..I'm node v10..I'll try this and tell you..thanks for your answer